# API Management in Bluemix and API Management on Cloud

Tags: api, ibm-cloud, ibm-api-management

My question is really about the difference between API Management in Bluemix and API Management on Cloud?

In the docs on Bluemix I can see

> "This service includes API versioning, lifecycle management, and API usage analytics."

In the knowledge center about the Cloud version is says

> "The API Management environment provides the following functions:
>
> - Manages the operations of the various servers in the API Management environment.
> - Provides the tools to interface with the various servers.
> - Provides analytic functions that collect and store information about APIs and API users.
> - Processes and manages security protocols and stores relevant user and appliance authentication data.
> - Provides assembly functions that enable APIs to integrate with various endpoints, such as databases or HTTP-based endpoints.".

So, is this the same?

Answer (score 0):

according to the documentation it is the same service. The differences should be related to available pricing plans, on Bluemix there is just one pricing plan.